# I wanted to get answer in double in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main ()
{
    double d,a,b;
    printf ("Enter number");
    scanf ("%d%d",&a,&b);
    d=b/a;
    printf ("\n %lf",d);
    getch();
}
```

I don't know what is wrong . It doesn't give answer in float or double.
Please suggest changes in c only because i am currently learning programming.
When it divides 2/1 gives 2 but 1/2 gives 0.000000

Comment: I continue to be amazed at Indian educational institutes and their propensity for using outdated 20-year-old technology like Borland C, especially when much better free options are available. Teaching students the use of `conio` and `getch` is not doing them any favours at all.

Comment: @paxdiablo Exploitation at it's core. Kanetkar writes book, finds career in high places to push book onto students who trust him, makes $$$... Years later, book still makes $$$ despite needing updates, book gets no updates... The world keeps spinnin'! Unfortunately, students are much quicker to jump on the "YOU'RE BEING RACIST" bandwagon than to realise something is *actually* wrong here and take steps locally to make drastic changes.

Comment: @paxdiablo As to the the veracity of your comment, it is subjective and irrelevant to OP's post - recommend deleting.  Type/`scanf()` specifier mis-match in `double d,a,b; ...  scanf ("%d%d",&a,&b);` is the issue.  Many compilers in many places on this planet will fail to warn (depending on options) and/or learners too often ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: Chux, that's why it was a comment rather than an answer and it's less subjective than you may think, being based on the evidence of the large number of questions on SO from Indians containing Borland-specific code which won't even compile in modern compilers, and earlier discussions on the matter here. It'd be interesting to analyse all the questions with borland/turbo/conio/etc and see what proportion could be tied to a specific educational system.

Comment: Still, if enough people complain, I'll remove the comment. Flagging the comment will also achieve that end, through SO's normal mechanisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%lf` in the `scanf` since `a` and `b` are of type `double`.

`%d` is for integer input.

Answer (score 2):

`%d` means to read an `int`.  `%f` will let you read a `float` type.  So change that in your `scanf` and you should be set

Comment: Except that there's nary a `float` anywhere *in* the OP's code. You should be using `%lf`.